# Can if-then-else logic be done in Redshift?

Tags: sql, if-statement, amazon-redshift

I am a newbie to `RedShift` but experienced with `MSSQL`. I was wondering if there's any way to write an if-then-else logic in `Redshift`?

Basically I want to run this logic in `Redshift`:

```
if ((select count(*) from a) - (select count(*) from b)) = 0 then 
   drop table a;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift doesn't support procedural statements, so you handle this best in your application code. If you must do it inside of SQL, something along the lines of this may help:

```
delete from a where (select count(*) from a) = (select count(*) from b);
```

This doesn't drop the table but deletes all rows from it when your condition is met.